# When I declare a class as internal, why does the IL show it as private?

Tags: c#, .net, cil

If I declare a class as internal, why does the IL show it as private?

```
internal class Thing

.class private auto ansi beforefieldinit Thing.Thing
       extends [mscorlib]System.Object
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From IL's point of view, `private` means *private to the assembly*, i.e. `internal` in C#.

In C#, it is not possible to mark types as `private` if they are not [nested](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173120.aspx). IL's equivalent accessibility for such types is `nested private`.

So we have:

- C#'s `internal` -> IL's `private` (to the assembly)
- C#'s `private` -> IL's `nested private` (to the enclosing type)

Comment: Thanks, I also noted that nested internal classes are marked: nested assembly.  Internal methods: assembly.

Comment: @JasonCarney For comparison, when using reflection, the instance property of `System.Type` which marks the accessibility is called `IsPublic` or `IsNotPublic` for the non-nested class, and is called `IsNestedPublic`, `IsNestedAssembly`, `IsNestedPrivate`, and so on, for the nested case. Only one of all those properties will return `true`. So for the case you asked for, which C# calls "internal" and CIL calls "private", the reflection API uses `IsNotPublic`.

Answer (score 4):

On [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183.aspx), it says:

> The C# keywords protected and internal have no meaning in IL and are
>   not used in the reflection APIs. The corresponding terms in IL are
>   Family and Assembly. To identify an internal method using reflection,
>   use the IsAssembly property. To identify a protected internal method,
>   use the IsFamilyOrAssembly.

So I guess it just makes them private, since they can't be accessed from elsewhere.

**EDIT:** I see how my answer might not be completely correct, I just thought it was something worth noting. The MSDN article I linked has some interesting stuff on this "what code we write" - "what it becomes" relationship.

Answer (score 3):

The mapping of C# keywords to IL keywords isn't always a logical one.  Ecma-335, section II.23.1.15 shows what flags are valid for a type.  You'll see that it only defines Public, NotPublic and a set of NestedXxx flags.  Nothing similar to "internal".  So your class is actually NotPublic, displayed as "private" in ildasm.

It is easy to see a side-effect of this: try this declaration in your C# code:

```
private class DoesNotWork {
}
```

You'll get:

> error CS1527: Elements defined in a namespace cannot be explicitly declared as private, protected, or protected internal