# Default Access modifier of a class in C#

Tags: c#, ildasm

The default Access modifier of a class in C# is internal.
But on inspecting the class with ildasm it shows class as private.

```
.class private auto ansi beforefieldinit ConsoleApplication1.Program
    extends [mscorlib]System.Object
    {
    } // end of class ConsoleApplication1.Program
```

Any idea why?

Comment: Who says it's internal?

Comment: Microsoft says it's internal: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx

Comment: possible duplicate of [When I declare a class as internal, why does the IL show it as private?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18660300/when-i-declare-a-class-as-internal-why-does-the-il-show-it-as-private)

Comment: Oh, my bad. I should really learn to read the whole question :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

IL does not have the concept of `internal`, internal classes are represented as `private` if they are in the root namespace or `assembly` if they are nested inside another type.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    internal class ExplicitInternal
    {
        private class ExplicitPrivate
        {
        }

        internal class ExplicitNestedInternal
        {
        }

        public class ExplicitNestedPublic
        {
        }
    }

    public class ExplicitPublic
    {
    }

    class ImplicitInternal
    {
        private class ImplicitPrivate
        {
        }
    }
}
```

becomes

```
.namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    .class private auto ansi beforefieldinit ConsoleApplication1.ExplicitInternal
        extends [mscorlib]System.Object
    {
        .class nested private auto ansi beforefieldinit ExplicitPrivate
            extends [mscorlib]System.Object
        {
        }

        .class nested assembly auto ansi beforefieldinit ExplicitNestedInternal
            extends [mscorlib]System.Object
        {
        }

        .class nested public auto ansi beforefieldinit ExplicitNestedPublic
            extends [mscorlib]System.Object
        {
        }
    }

    .class public auto ansi beforefieldinit ConsoleApplication1.ExplicitPublic
        extends [mscorlib]System.Object
    {
    }

    .class private auto ansi beforefieldinit ConsoleApplication1.ImplicitInternal
        extends [mscorlib]System.Object
    {
        .class nested private auto ansi beforefieldinit ImplicitPrivate
            extends [mscorlib]System.Object
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1, Here is the documentation link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183.aspx "The C# keywords protected and internal have no meaning in IL and are not used in the reflection APIs."

Answer (score 3):

The general rule for the default access modifier is going to be the least accessibility possible.  [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx) goes into more detail:

> Classes and structs that are declared directly within a namespace (in
>   other words, that are not nested within other classes or structs) can
>   be either public or internal. **Internal is the default** if no access
>   modifier is specified. Struct members, including nested classes and
>   structs, can be declared as public, internal, or private. Class
>   members, including nested classes and structs, can be public,
>   protected internal, protected, internal, or private. The access level
>   for class members and struct members, including nested classes and
>   structs, **is private by default.**

...

> The type of any member that is a field, property, or event **must be
>   at least as accessible as the member itself.**

So in C# these are the rules, however I agree with comments that the particular issue you are dealing with is ultimately due to internal [having no meaning in IL.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183.aspx)

Comment: You should elaborate on this a little bit, and probably provide some relevant documentation

Comment: In other words, `internal` if it's a top-level type (effectively "assembly-private"), and `private` if it's a nested type.

Comment: @user1426187 Because IL modifiers do not necessarily map directly to C# modifiers.

Comment: `private` is default access specifier for class members, The reason OP is seeing it as private is because Reflection / IL doesn't have any meaning for internal, see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183.aspx

Comment: @Habib - Can you explain why class members are relevant?  The OP asked about the default access modifier of a class.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey, I am not saying that class members are relevant, I am just saying that the reason IL is showing an internal class as private is because of the reflection/IL, since internal doesn't have any meaning in IL, its private to assembly.

Answer (score 1):

Is it an inner class? Would be private then.

Answer (score 0):

Class cannot be created as private by default because for soin that class must be at least nested inside another class.
ILDASM show you that class is private because it's mean that class limited in scope to the type in which its declared.
If a class is not declared inside the definition of a type then it cannot be private to that type. So, nested classes are private by default while non-nested classes are internal by default.
If you dont add some access modifies it's automatically adopt to access level. means

```
class Myclass1 {
     class MyNestedClass
     {
     }
}
```

i the same like

```
internal class Myclass1 {
     private class MyNestedClass
     {
     }
}
```

Additional information [MSDN1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ba0a1yw2.aspx)  and [MSDN2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5ka91b.aspx)